# How to store year in Django

Tags: mysql, django

What would be the best way to store year (YYYY) in a django model? I'm using a mysql backend.

```
start_year = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

??

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your solution. Is there a reason you don't want to store more date information?

Comment: I don't have more information to store. I'm just given a year that a product was released, but it doesn't contain the actual date of release.

Comment: Renenber you can [write your custom model field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On second thought, since you're storing years, make it nonnegative.

```
start_year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Other that this looking better, would there be any difference between the two fields?

Comment: I just checked MySQL and it won't prevent you from inserting a negative number, but you may get some validation help from Django. Feel free to research it if you like.